# jquery makeArray then split

Tags: jquery, arrays, split

Im making a select list of all labels in my form. The select list will then be used to chose each form field.  The form will be similar to Amazons main search box but with various field types.

The issue is the labels aren't being split correctly and so, the option values arent displaying correctly.

if anyone can provide feedback, it would be very helpful as i've been on this for a while now.

thank you and let me know if you have any other questions.

```
$.fn.menuForm = function(){
var _fo = $("form");
var _hi = $(_fo).find(".views-widget");
var _ho = $(".views-exposed-widget").not(".views-submit-button");
var _lb = $(".views-exposed-widget label").text();

$(_fo).before("<span id='expand'>Search</span>");
$(_fo).find(".views-submit-button").insertAfter("form");
$(_fo).find(".views-reset-button input").appendTo(".views-submit-button");
$("body").append("<select id='selopt'><option></option></select>");

var arr = [];

var arr = $.makeArray(_lb);
var opts = arr.slice('');
var sel = "";
alert(opts);

$.each(opts,function(i){
    sel += '<option value="'+opts[i]+'">'+opts[i]+'</option>';
});
$('#selopt').append(sel);

$("input[type='text']").change(function(){
    $(this).closest(".views-exposed-widget").find("label").addClass("_s").show();
});
};
$(this).menuForm();
```

here is my progress: 
http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/swDy5/3/

Comment: It would be easier to know the expected result. by only saying *"I'm having trouble splitting the array"* does not point clearly to your real issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of querying for all labels, sticking the text into an array,then splitting it back out again to populate your html, you could just iterate over each element as you find it:

```
$("body").append("<select id='selopt'><option></option></select>");

var sel = "";
$(".views-exposed-widget label").each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    sel += '<option value="'+ text +'">'+ text+'</option>';
});
$('#selopt').append(sel);
```

Comment: Thanks. Im going to go with this answer.  Would i be able to use the text variable outside of the function? Im trying to compare text var to what the user selects

Comment: Not directly, You can either query the user selection inside the `.each` function or you can push the values into an array and check against the array after the loop.

Comment: I now have the values in an array.  I just need to compare array to $("#selopt").val() on change. Almost got it but i guess ill post a new question.

Comment: new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951910/jquery-find-matching-selected-option-and-label-to-display-corresponding-field

Answer (score 1):

I think the `$.makeArray` only gets html elements.. remove `.text()` and change your `$.each` loop
to this

```
$.each(arr,function(){
    sel += '<option value="'+$(this).text()+'">'+$(this).text()+'</option>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".views-exposed-widget label").each(function(){
        $("#selopt").append("<option value="+$(this).text()+">"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
    });
```

see the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swDy5/4/)