# Jquery - find matching selected option and label to display corresponding field

Tags: jquery, forms, match

Solved:
http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/swDy5/20/

Goal is to create an amazon style search box which will reduce the amount of space needed for  multiple input search/filter fields all on one page.

**Search Flow:**

obtain labels from the search form.
append labels to a select option field.

on select change, obtain selected value.

If selected val matches a label, display closest div.input,div.option **(This is where it all goes wrong. Since im searching an array, i don't think i can locate the closest hidden container near the label. Any tips?)**

So far, I have passed the new select values to an array and have attempted to find a match on change.

```
    $("body").append("<select id='selopt'></select>");

var _op = [];
var _se = "";
$(".views-exposed-widget label").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    _se += '<option value="'+ text +'">'+ text +'</option>';
    _op.push($(this).text());
    // Monthly Release,Title,New Provider/Show Name
});


$("#selopt").change(function() {
 $("form .views-exposed-widget .views-widget").fadeOut();
    _op[$(this).val()].next('div').css("z-index","100").fadeIn();
    });
```

Updated Jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/swDy5/14/

Comment: if this is an odd method of doing this, please offer suggestions. :-)

Comment: Going to utilize inArray() and will post back

Comment: So you have populated your drop down, and an array, when the dropdown changes, what is it you want to do? Since the dropdown and array are populated together, it will always find a match...

Comment: Thats correct about always finding a match. When the drop down changes, I would like the closest hidden div to display.I might be approaching this wrong tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show the closest div to the dropdown that is also hidden.

```
$("#selopt").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('div:hidden').show();
});
```

**Update**

Based on your comment this should get you close. Instead of pushing the text into an array, we can create a dictionary of the text to the actual label. Then when the selection changes use the label to find the closest div. Like so:

```
$("body").append("<select id='selopt'></select>");

var _op = {};
var _se = "";
$(".views-exposed-widget label").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    _se += '<option value="'+ text +'">'+ text +'</option>';
    _op[$(this).text()] = $(this);
    // Monthly Release,Title,New Provider/Show Name
});


$("#selopt").change(function() {
     _op[$(this).val()].closest('div:hidden').show();
});
```

This may have unexpected results if the text of the labels have special characters. In which case we can modify our array a bit more, but still possible.

Comment: I have a feeling you also want to work with the selected value of the dropdown when it changes. To do this you can `$(this).val()` inside the change function.

Comment: ok, I don't think Im after the closest hidden div nearest #selopt. Im after the closest hidden div near the label text. Sorry, i might be making things more confusing than they need to be.